# tbody . each( ) ; method missing watir

Tags: watir

Hi there I am not sure if i am using the wrong watir syntax or if there is something wrong with my watir. Below if the code that I am writing to go through each row of a table body. Be

```
e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main").tbody(:class => "blacklabel").each(){|i|.....}
```

when i run this code i get a missing error code. Also when i try

e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main").tbody(:class => "blacklabel").length()

I get a missing method error. Below is the website that i am using.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to iterate over the rows collection rather than the table body - ie you need to call `rows()` before the `each()`. So you want to do:

```
my_table = e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main").tbody(:class => "blacklabel")
my_table.rows.each{|i|.....}
```

The tbody element uses the TableSection class. The TableSection API can be seen here - http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-classic/Watir/TableSection.